# Container for time stamp organization

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, heap

the following is an excerpt from some code I have.

the hpp:

```
class message_receiver
{
    struct Chunk
    {
        // inits timestamp and other data memebers
        Chunk();
        boost::uint64_t m_timeStamp;
        bool last;
        std::vector<std::string> m_message;
        ...
    };

    struct Compare
    {
        bool operator()(const boost::shared_ptr<Chunk> p_left, const
             boost::shared_ptr<Chunk> p_right) const
        {
            return p_left.m_timeStamp > p_right.m_timeStamp;
        }
    };

    std::vector< boost::shared_ptr<Chunk> > m_chunks;
    void setTimeStamp(const boost::shared_ptr<Chunk>& p_ca, bool isNew)
   //other stuff

};
```

the cpp:

```
void message_receiver::setTimeStamp(const boost::shared_ptr<Chunk>& p_ca, bool isNew)
{
    p_ca->m_timeStamp = boost::chrono::duration_cast<boost::chrono::microseconds>(
    boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();

    if (isNew)
    {
        m_chunks.push_back(p_ca);
        std::push_heap(m_chunks.begin(), m_chunks.end(), Compare());
    }
    else
    {
        std::make_heap(m_chunks.begin(), m_chunks.end(), Compare());
    }
}
```

Ultimately, setting the timestamp is done in a loop. So this function gets called many times, which should keep all of the time stamps in min heap order

I want to keep the stamps in min heap order so the oldest time stamp is readily available at the front of my vector for getting. Which is done with std::pop_heap (which is not shown). This is done with the idea that I need sequential access.

So my first question is the std::make heap call in the else statement. Should that be done? I scoured the documentation for a while and I didn't see any other way to actually go about amending heap order unless std::pop_heap or push heap are used, but in one case all I do is update the object. I assume the heap order is probably not maintained when I do that? Is there a better way to restore the heap property after the update?

Secondly, I realized that this code would be calling min-heapify every time I update a time stamp which is an algorithm with O(n) complexity. Which is a bit slow for my needs. I looked in to using the boost Fibonacci heap, but after some research it seems like it would only be more efficient when reducing the size and ultimately doesn't provide a large performance boost. After much research I haven't been able to find a container that efficiently suites my needs so are you aware of any other containers that could possibly work better here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not convinced that the heap is your best choice here.

There are several self-organizing trees that have the properties you seem to be after.

I'd suggesting using such a tree ([treap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treap)) and just reinserting the element that is modified.

> **Q.** *After much research I haven't been able to find a container that efficiently suites my needs so are you aware of any other containers that could possibly work better here?*

I'd look at the various tree containers in Boost Intrusive.

- e.g. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/intrusive/treap_set_multiset.html#intrusive.treap_set_multiset.treap_set_multiset_containers

Boost Intrusive is somewhat peculiar in usage but it looks very much like it's exactly what you want to do here anyways (since Intrusive containers never *own* the elements that they contain).